# Error message on when charting efficient frontier in r studios

Tags: r, r-portfolioanalytics

When I run this line of code, I get the error message:

```
chart.RiskReward(maxret, risk.col = "StdDev", return.col = "mean",
                 chart.assets = "False")
chart.EfficientFrontier(maxret, match.col="StdDev", n.portfolios=100, type="l", tangent.line=FALSE)

Error in seq.default(from = minret, to = maxret, length.out = n.portfolios) :
  'from' must be a finite number
```

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with. There's very little information here for us to go on

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: errors message occurs when I run a line of code that chart the efficient frontier,original script below: 
# Run the optimization
maxret <- optimize.portfolio(R=returns_data, momentargs=momentargs, portfolio=portf_maxret, optimize_method="ROI", trace=TRUE)
 
 
#Charts
chart.RiskReward(maxret, risk.col = "StdDev", return.col = "mean",
                 chart.assets = "False")
chart.EfficientFrontier(maxret, match.col="StdDev", n.portfolios=100, type="l", tangent.line=FALSE)
chart.Weights.EF(maxret, match.col="StdDev")
chart.Weights.EF(maxret, match.col="StdDev", by.groups=TRUE)